# Capture webcam video frames without canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, webcam

I need to capture webcam video data and send it while streaming to another server. Now I can do it sending it frame by frame calculating the framerate before, but not sure if it's the best practice.

Another issue I face, is how to manage with it in case I cannot have a DOM access to create html5 video element. Now I'm getting canvas info with capture function, but supposing not DOM, or even not to being able to displaying it none.

```
 navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
       navigator.mozGetUserMedia);

       navigator.getMedia (
         {
              video: true,
              audio: false
            },
            function(localMediaStream) {   
              var video = document.getElementById('video');
              video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
              video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                 var stream = capture(video);
                 $.post( "another-server.com/sendvideo", function(stream ) {
                (...)


capture  = function(video, scaleFactor) {
      //scaleFactor: optional param to resize the img if needed
      if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
      } 
      var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
      var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
          canvas.height = h;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);

      return canvas;
    }
```

Comment: tl;dr :\ ...something like WebRTC? - if you don't want canvas and an imageData, than could you simply send the actual data?

Comment: Could you ectend on what you call "no DOM access"? How can you get access to gUM but not DOM ? If you mean that you don't want to happen anything in the document, then don't all thos can be done offscreen.